# Comparing two tables in a database matching values and writing/merging to a new table

Tags: php, sql, database

I am trying to do a simple match up my IDs in my database and collate all information into the one table. My database details are as follows.

```
Database Name: test
Table Names: password, username
Password Table contains: id, password
Username Table contains: id, username
```

Can anyone please provide me with some code examples so I can read the relevant username and password next to each other in one list without having to crossreference between the two tables, matching up the ID? for example a table like

```
ID, Username, Password
```

Comment: If you're banking on the ID's being auto_incremented and matching up, you're going to have a bad time. If you must do it this way, you need to have a relational table for `user_passwords` with the columns `user_id` and `password_id` to link the information together. Then you can use a JOIN statement to get exactly what you're looking for. I think you might be over complicating it though, just have a user's table with their id, username and password as columns.

Comment: The point of using a relational database is to relate the data together, usually through IDs... how else will you know if the password belongs to the correct user? Or do you just mean a query to display them without also displaying the IDs? Also I hope those passwords are encrypted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming both tables share the same ID, you can use a join query for that:

```
SELECT     `username`.`ID`, `Username`, `Password`
FROM       `username`
INNER JOIN `password`
ON         `password`.`ID` = `username`.`ID`
```

But I personally think it would make your life a whole lot easier to just store both pieces of information in the same table.

Comment: Thanks for this, although it didnt seem to match up the correct password to the correct user / id